# How to increase latest number inside string and parenthesis in Ruby (Rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a string like this:

```
Hello (0)
```

also can have this too:

```
Hello 12345 (0) (1) (65)
```

What im trying to do is increase last number. In this case expected result will be like this:

```
Hello (1)
Hello 12345 (0) (1) (66)
```

Is there any way to do this magically in Ruby or regex? How can i keep all numbers in all parenthesis but increase the last one?

Note that, string can have unicode letters in it so the result should not be broken.

Comment: There's no such thing as magic. Please show us your attempt. :)

Comment: Does the string always end with a number in parentheses?

Comment: What is the code you are having trouble with? What trouble do you have with your code? Do you get an error message? What is the error message? Is the result you are getting not the result you are expecting? What result do you expect and why, what is the result you are getting and how do the two differ? Is the behavior you are observing not the desired behavior? What is the desired behavior and why, what is the observed behavior, and in what way do they differ? Please, provide a [mcve].

Comment: Sorry guys! @kiddorails, i know i was referring for regex pattern. I did not tried anything because i do not even where to start. Question is simple and answers are correct.

Comment: @Stefan, sorry mate for not seeing your question. Yes, string always and only end with parenthesis and number in it.

Comment: @Pratha it's easy then: `"Hello (0)".succ` returns `"Hello (1)"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
str = "Hello 12345 (0) (1) (65) (33a)"

str.sub(/.*\(\d+\)/, &:succ)
  #=> "Hello 12345 (0) (1) (66) (33a)"
```

`.*` is greedy so it gobbles up all characters, including `'(0)'` and `'(1)'`, until it gets to the last match of `\(\d+\)`.

Comment: I've choose this as an answer. Dead simple and loved the `succ` function here. Works well. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

First find the last parenthesised part

```
/\(.*\)[^\(\)]*\z/
```

This finds a pair of parentheses with something inside it, followed by any non-parentheses until the end of the string.

Next, bind that to a variable.

```
/\((?<lastnum>.*)\)[^\(\)]*\z/ =~ input_string
```

Finally build the output string.

```
if /\A(?<prior>.*)\((?<lastnum>.*)\)[^\(\)]*\z/ =~ input_string
    "#{prior}(#{lastnum + 1})"
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Regex can scan for teh different parts:

```
> s = "Hello 12345 (0) (1) (65)"
> value = s.scan(/((.*)\((\d+)\)\z)/).first
```

This will match any string, followed by a '(', followed by any number of digits, followed by ')' then the end of the string. You then have an array, which you can manipulate. The (unescaped) parenthesis in the pattern above groups the inputs:

value is ["Hello 12345 (0) (1) (65)", "Hello 12345 (0) (1) ", "65"]

It's then a case of putting them together

```
"#{value[1]}(#{value[2].to_i + 1})"
```

Obviously this doesn't deal with error cases etc but gives you a start

Answer (score 1):

You can use this regex to achieve what you want

```
\((\d+)\)(?!.*\(\d+\))
```

In ruby you can use the following code to change your string

```
"Hello 12345 (0) (1) (66)".str.sub(/\((\d+)\)(?!.*\(\d+\))/) { |s| s.succ }

// => Hello 12345 (0) (1) (67)
```

Comment: This doesn't take parentheses into account.